Heap with Non Clustered Index vs. Non-Sequential Clustered Index
I work with an enterprise application (code not available) that currently uses heaps. It uses a terrible pseudo-sequential varchar key that ends up not being sequential due to string sorting not taking length into account (ex. ABCD is sorted after ABC but before BCD).
For SELECT performance, we still have covering non-clustered indexes on the key column (among many other non-clustered indexes for other columns).
My first question is, given that INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE (rare) still need to update both the heap and the non-clustered index, is there any performance benefit in using the heap, or would a clustered index (even on this non-sequential key) have the same 'relative' performance?
My reasoning is that while, yes, inserts into the heap are faster for non-sequential keys, the non-clustered index will also require updating which would take (I believe) an equivalent time - but at least all of the other benefits of having a clustered index will be available.
My second question is what will fragmentation look like with such a pseudo-sequential key? Will SQL-Server continually fragment the clustered index? Or is the fact that inserts are mostly sequential helpful to keep fragmentation low?

Microsoft documentation highlights when to use and when not to use heaps, which you can review in heaps-tables-without-clustered-indexes. A heap is preferable when a table is frequently truncated and reloaded and when a clustered key has no practical use (e.g., not used by ORDER BY clauses or references by other tables). However, using a heap is not ideal for tables with frequent updates, as updates can lead to data relocation, causing pointers to point to different locations, (we also call this fragmentation). I highly recommend reading the Microsoft note for detail info to consider which best suits your data.
Regarding your second question:

If the index key is sequential, INSERT will always go to the right-hand side of the index and will never be inserted into a middle of a page, thus INSERT will not cause fragmentation

If I understand correctly, as you mentioned, the index key in your table is not generated sequentially, INSERT is more likely to cause fragmentation (e.g., due to middle page splits).

DELETE or UPDATE variable-length columns, on the other hand can cause fragmentation, refer to Unexpected Clustered Index Fragmentation for more details.

However, fragmentation should not be a significant concern, I recommend reading Stop Worrying About SQL Server Fragmentation. Optimizing your workload to leverage the cache effectively—through query tuning and reducing logical reads—or adding more cache to support your workload can minimize disk access. Additionally, you can set up a weekly index maintenance schedule to rebuild or reorganize highly fragmented indexes using well-written script such as this one SQL Server Index and Statistics Maintenance by Ola Hallengren


If you decide to use a clustered index for your table, this is an excellent reference to create Effective Clustered Indexes.
Examples of good clustering keys include:

An identity column
A composite key of date and identity – in the order (date, identity)
A pseudo sequential GUID (using the NEWSEQUENTIALID() function in SQL Server)

GUIDs generated with the NEWID() function or by the client (e.g., .NET) can be poor choices because they are non-sequential (prone to fragmentation) and large in size.

Thank you for the response. I have no option to change the key type unfortunately, so it has to remain a sequentially increasing string ('A', 'B' .. 'Z', 'AA', 'AB'...) - meaning it is not very sequential from a clustering perspective as 'AA' would be inserted after 'A' and before 'B'. Deletes and updates on variable length columns are very rare. Thanks again, and any further suggestions/information based on this would be much appreciated!


what will fragmentation look like with such a pseudo-sequential key?

It depends on how many "insert points" the code causes in the B-Tree.  If inserts mostly land on the last page or a finite number of points in the sort order then fragmentation won't be bad.
For a detailed discussion see: Good Page Splits and Sequential GUID Key Generation

Oh wow, that link is wonderful for given clarity to how this clustering key will behave. In a lot of ways my pseudo-sequential string is a lot like the sequential GUID - it should only create bad page splits on string length changes (which happens far less frequently).
